# C++ expression must have class type on my class

Tags: c++, class

I am really confused at the error 'expression must have class type' on `newHTTP` on line 13

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <WinHttp.h>
    #include "myHTTP.h"

    int main()
    {

        WinHTTP newHTTP();

// error is here
        HINTERNET myResponse = newHTTP.httpConnect(L"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36",
            L"http://api",
            0,
            L"GET");


        //
        int x;
        std::cin >> x;

        return 0;
    }
```

I just dont understand what im missing, i have specified HINTERNET on myresponse and made sure the method httpConnect returns a value. Can someone assist? 
My class code (trimmed of course):

```
    class WinHTTP {

    private:
        std::string siteUsername, sitePassword;
        std::wstring UA, URL;
        bool bResult = false;
        DWORD dwSize = sizeof(DWORD); // used to handle reading data in bytes
        LPSTR pszOutBuffer; // used to Allocate space for the buffer.
        DWORD dwDownloaded = 0; // set to null if using asynchronously and use in callback function only
        HINTERNET hSession = NULL, hConnect = NULL, hRequest = NULL;

    public:
        WinHTTP(std::string myuser, std::string mypass) : siteUsername(myuser), sitePassword(mypass){

        }

        // TODO: update to be able to add proxy details either here or before. do check if proxy has been detected in here and open/connect accordingly 
        HINTERNET httpConnect(std::wstring userAgent, std::wstring myURL, int isHTTPS, std::wstring protocol) {

            UA = userAgent;
            URL = myURL;

            std::wstring acceptTypes = L"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";

            int portToUse;
            if (isHTTPS == 1) {
                portToUse = 443;
            }
            else {
                portToUse = 80;
            }

            //initialize http and return session handle -- use c_str to convert wstring to LPCWSTR
            hSession = WinHttpOpen(UA.c_str(),
                WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

            //make the connection request
            if (hSession) {
                hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, URL.c_str(), portToUse, 0);
            }
            else {
                printf("error: %d",GetLastError());
            }

            // open the request - not connected at this point
            hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, protocol.c_str(), NULL, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, 0);

            if (hRequest) {
                return hRequest;
            }
            else {
                printf("error: %d", GetLastError());
                return hRequest;

            }
        }
};
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add a comment on the line you get the errors. And please copy (as text) the full and complete error, including possible informational notes, and paste it into the question without modifications.

Comment: As far as your example shows, you don't have a default constructor for `WinHTTP`, so you should provide two `std::string`s when creating it here: `WinHTTP newHTTP();`

Comment: `WinHTTP newHTTP();` -- This does not create an object.  This declares a function called `newHTTP()` that takes no arguments and returns a `WinHTTP`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen i do? on line 13 of my class code has constructor

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie your saying i cant create objects like that? everywhere i see thats how you declare a instance of a class

Comment: @jimmy -- No, you don't see this everywhere.  Actually you don't find that anywhere in creating an object like that in C++ if the constructor has no arguments.

Comment: You have a constructor with 2 parameters. So you need to pass those two parameters to create an object.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so please help me and post an answer? are you saying if i pass parameters to WinHTTP newHTTP(); it will suddenly make it a valid object?

Comment: @jimmy First, your class must be constructed with two arguments.  Second, even if your class takes no arguments as a constructor, the proper way would be `WinHTTP newHTTP;`, as proposed by the links given in the previous comments concerning "most vexing parse".

Answer (score -3):

Please add default constructor if you invoking one . I see only parametrized one .

Comment: `WinHTTP newHTTP();` Doesn't even try to invoke default constructor. Consider reading about [Most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work).

Comment: Oh . I didn't know that . Thanks